# Search for name when input text is separated

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I want to be able to search for a prductname, for example : Product C202

But If a user inputs "Product C 202", i want to be able to find that anyway.

We are using this now and it works for 99% of the time, but not when the above is given.

"search": "(Product*) + (c*) + (202*)"

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard searches with '*' are most often slow as they go through an additional layer of expansion. I recommend synonyms in this case; C 202 and C202 can be defined as synonyms. For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/synonym-map-operations.